# Altium port rotate

Tags: schematics, altium

In Altium Designer, I am trying to place a input port to the right of a symbol like in the picture. But I want to rotate the port 180 degrees so the pointy part points left instead of right. Whenever I press X or space it always points right or down (in case I press space). How can I make the port point left?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is just a some extra info for you - the bus wire serves no purpose other than a graphical representation that this is a bus. You can create a bus with just net names and a port and Altium will not know the difference.

Comment: This is a side issue, but you need to be careful how you use the buses and how you name them. You need to read this, paying attention to the "Using Buses" section, and especially the part about logical buses. http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Connectivity+and+Multi-Sheet+Design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the port to right side. Altium will change the port direction automatically. Wire will be disconnected. Then drag the wire and connect to the port.

Comment: It's not clear from the way you wrote this, but Altium doesn't (as far as I recall) auto-rotate the port until you connect the wire to it. (And I'm not 100% sure it works with busses, since I never use them)

Comment: I moved the port all the way to the right and it doesn't work.

Comment: It works with buses. But the port name should be VIDOUT(7..0) not (7:0)

Comment: Yes!! Renaming the bus and moving it did the trick! Thanks!!!

Comment: I tried marking up the answer but I don't have enough reputation yet! :P